# Ubuntu 12.04 Synaptic tooltips are white on yellow

Tags: synaptic, tooltip

Ubuntu 12.04/Precise Gnome Classic (no effects) Metacity 
GnomishDark theme

Hi,
Any ideas/suggestions on how to change the Synaptic white on yellow tooltip color ?

Thanks-in-advance,
- Robert

Comment: Have you tried changing the theme?

Answer (score 0):

Change the superuser's theme, and/or ensure that the theme you want (without the ugly tooltips) is installed in `/usr/share/themes` so that it will be in the same location for the superuser as for your normal account and the superuser can use it upon starting.